# Are there any known issues with NPM or Node.js when creating a new app?

Tags: npm, expo, node-modules, npm-install

I've successfully installed Node.js and NPM on my machine, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to create a new React Native app. After entering the command in the terminal, nothing happens, despite having a stable internet connection. Can anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated, and sharing any insights could benefit others facing similar challenges.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Terminal View]